# Get battery charging level of Razer mouse and keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, mouse, power-management, battery

I'm looking for a way to get the battery charging level of my wireless "Razer Pro Type" keyboard and "Pro Click" mouse, both connected with a 2.4GHz USB dongle.
There is an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248006/how-can-i-see-the-battery-status-of-my-logitech-wireless-mouse) for Logitech with `upower --dump`  or "Solaar", but I don't get any informations with it for my mouse/keyboard.

I hoped and tried to get something with `lsusb -v` and executed it with `watch -d` while charging to see any changes, but there wasn't any.
There are also [articles for bluetooth-devices](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset#Battery_level_reporting), but unfortunately I wasn't able to use those for my case using the dongle.

It doesn't have to be any fancy with GUI etc., I can work with it, if I only get the information about the charging level in any form. Does anyone know if and where the charging level of such devices can be looked up?

Comment: Have you tried any of these? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117563/check-bluetooth-headphones-battery-status-in-linux

Comment: What driver are you using ? (I personally use https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer ) It comes with a daemon which include misc battery notification features. Is this daemon running on your system ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Ad 1: Yes, I tried bluetoothctl like in the Wiki-article I liked. I will take a deeper look into you askubunu-question. But I'm not too confident, because my devices are not connected via bluetooth

Ad 2: I don't use any additional drivers, so "only" those comming with the kernel. I also took a look into openrazer, but unfortunately the tickets of both of my devices are still open, so I didn't tried them. Are you using them with a Razer Pro Click/Type or with other Razer-devices?